# Something appeared below my cats eye in 12 hours

Tags: cats, health

Something appeared below my cat's eye. and 12 hours before, there was nothing.

This was him **yesterday 00:00**

[image]

This is him **12 hours later on**

[image]

First I thought that he might have had scratched himself somewhere, but now, this is him **24 hours later on**, right now.

[image]

To me it seems like it has grown a little.

We found out this week that he has 3 tumors, 2 in the kidney and one in the intestines. Due to this, he has been barely eating and has lost a lot of weight.

We have a doctor's appointment today, but I would like to know your comments, if you have any idea what the cause could be.

Could be it be mushrooms? Could it be due to malnutrition? Could it be that he has cancer and it has metastasized?

I really have no idea what kind of "thing" could grow THAT FAST!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two alternatives here: your cat has a bad tooth and the infection (and pain) makes eating problematic.

Or your cat has got a scratch that has become infected giving your cat pain when he tries to eat. The infection itself might make your cat ill so he is loosing his appetite.

It looks like your cat has got an abcess. This is very common in cats and your vet will need to open it up and flush it clean with salt water. If this is from a scratch your cat probably won't need antibiotics.

If it comes from a bad tooth your vet will remove the tooth and give your cat antibiotics and a painkiller.

Please do not worry, this is easy to fix for your vet. I'm sure this is less serious than you might think.

Comment: The bad eating was before this spot appeared. And we already got his teeth checked.

Comment: please give an update after you have been at the vet and tell me how it goes and do not worry it is very unlikely to be cancer or any thing you have done wrong.

Comment: I agree this looks like a blister, cyst or abscess (or whatever you want to call a fluid-filled cavity in soft tissue). Cancer is a growth of cells and often manifests as bumps right below the skin. Only in extremely rare and severe cases does the cancer grow through the skin and become visible outside of the body. And that looks nothing like what your cat has. It could be that the root of a canine is infected. They're rooted so deep in the skull that the infection can break through below the eye.

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent No, I did not misread your question. Your cat has tumors. This *still* doesn't look anything like a tumor. I might be mistraken, I'm not a vet, but I'm also not aware of any tumor that could grow so fast. It's obviously itching (hence the hair loss from scratching) so you should still let a vet take a look at it. But there's no need to panic and assume your cat suddenly transforms into Deadpool. That's not how cancer works in reality.

Comment: In the end, my vet said that my cat does have an infection. Thanks for the advice. Also +1 for Deadpool.